# NumPy array holding .wav audio data for sounddevice

Tags: python, numpy, audio

I would like to use sounddevice's [playrec](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.3/#sounddevice.playrec) feature. To start I would like to just get [sd.play()](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.3/#sounddevice.play) to work, I am new to Python and have never worked with NumPy, I have gotten audio to play using pyaudio, but I need the simultaneous play record feature in sounddevice. When I try to play an audio .wav file I get: TypeError: Unsupported data type: 'string288'. I think it has something to do with having to store the .wav file in a numpy array, but I have no idea how to do that. Here is what I have:

```
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np

sd.default.samplerate = 44100
sd.play('test.wav')
sd.wait
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of sounddevice.play() says:

```
sounddevice.play(data, samplerate=None, mapping=None, blocking=False, loop=False, **kwargs)
```

where data is an "array-like".

It can't work with an audio file name, as you tried. The audio file has first to be read, and interpreted as a numpy array.
This code should work:

```
data, fs = sf.read(filename, dtype='float32')
sd.play(data, fs)
```

You'll find more examples [here](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.3/examples.html).

Comment: Thanks @sandoval31, this worked! I just had to make sure Pysoundfile dependency https://github.com/bastibe/PySoundFile was installed. I remember seeing this example but at first it was to confusing, this really cleared it up for me, thanks!